# How can I create a datetime generator that can be used as an input for the graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, timeserieschart

I want to plot a real time, time series data using plotly. But I need a datetime generator to be created first that will act as an input to the plot. I also want to limit the graph to show data for latest 30 mins records only.

the below code is in javascript, I want to perform something similar in python:

```
function rand() {
  return Math.random();
}

var time = new Date();

var data = [{
  x: [time],
  y: [rand],
  mode: 'lines',
  line: {color: '#80CAF6'}
}]

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

var cnt = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {

  var time = new Date();

  var update = {
  x:  [[time]],
  y: [[rand()]]
  }

  var olderTime = time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() - 1);
  var futureTime = time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 1);

  var minuteView = {
        xaxis: {
          type: 'date',
          range: [olderTime,futureTime]
        }
      };

  Plotly.relayout('myDiv', minuteView);
  Plotly.extendTraces('myDiv', update, [0])

  if(++cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It would help to understand your poblem if you post some code that you already have.